# Store textbox value into a string?

Tags: c#

I am making a random number generator in a form application and the user will type a number in a text box. When user clicks on the OK button. the text in the textbox will be stored in a string value. for example;

```
if (ButtonOK is clicked)
{
    String a = textbox1;
    int b = int.Parse(a);
}
```

Then the value of the textbox will become a labels value. for example:

```
b = label1.Text;
```

how do i do that?
I would be really happy if anyone could help me solve this problem.

SOLVED thanks to  Soner Gönül

Comment: Is this supposed to be ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you need something like;

```
private void ButtonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = textbox1.Text;
    int b;
    if (Int32.TryParse(a, out b))
    {
        label1.Text = b.ToString();       
    }
}
```

Comment: even `b` don't need to be initialised :)

Comment: @Sudhakar Ups, missed that. Thanks.

Comment: i hope this is what exactly OP is looking for :)

Comment: but what do you mean with the TryParse bit?

Comment: ok, i got it. you did so instead of int b = int.Parse(a); right?

Comment: @user3024531 The `TryParse` method is like the `Parse` method, except the `TryParse` method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails. It eliminates the need to use exception handling to test for a `FormatException` in the event that s is invalid and cannot be successfully parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming is a WinForm application just drag a button and a textbox on the form, double click on the button and write this code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  int max;
  if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out max))
  {
        label1.Text = "Not a number";
  }
  else
  {
      Random r = new Random();
      int random = r.Next(max);
      label1.Text = string.Format("Random number: {0}", random);
  }
}
```

Comment: nice to see your exlanation from the beginning(dragging button on to the form), writing actual part inside  if block is much better and i don't suggest to create Random() object inside the if/else block as it can generate duplicate random numbers instead of that create a static object and call Next method every time

Comment: see this common pit fall => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number

Comment: Yes but for a simple example like that this should be enough.

Comment: Thank you! this one was really good, but i did not want to create a new messagebox. i wanted to change a value on a label.